# TextView extension throws NumberFormatException when trying to render bold style on Android Studio preview

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a class which extends TextView and has some code to support text styles, however I get an error when Android Studio tries to render it on the preview pane.

I'm including the stack trace and the class code below

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "bold"   at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)   at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)   at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils_Delegate.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils_Delegate.java:72)   at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:93)   at android.util.BridgeXmlPullAttributes.getAttributeIntValue(BridgeXmlPullAttributes.java:134)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeXmlBlockParser.getAttributeIntValue(BridgeXmlBlockParser.java:436)   at com.myproject.util.BlockTextView.applyCustomFont(BlockTextView.java:35)   at com.myproject.meuprimeiroapp.util.BlockTextView.(BlockTextView.java:24)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)   at

```
private void applyCustomFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    int textStyle = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_SCHEMA, "textStyle", Typeface.NORMAL);

    Typeface customFont = selectTypeface(context, textStyle);
    setTypeface(customFont);
}
```

Code based on this article:
[Custom Fonts on Android — Using Font Styles](https://futurestud.io/blog/custom-fonts-on-android-using-font-styles)

Comment: Can  I see your code?

Comment: sure, but what else do you want to see? the code is the same of the one you can find on the provided link (at the very bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying Artem's solution I kept getting the weirdest inflation errors, even after adding some try/catch code.

Turns out the string values returned by getAttributeValue come in as "0x0, "0x1" and such, not as "normal", "bold". So I'm sharing below a working solution based on Artem's tip.

```
 private void applyCustomFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    String style = "0x0";
    try {
        style = attrs.getAttributeValue(ANDROID_SCHEMA, "textStyle");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int textStyle;
    if (style != null && style.equals("0x1")) {
        textStyle = Typeface.BOLD;
    }else{
        textStyle = Typeface.NORMAL;
    }

    Typeface customFont = selectTypeface(context, textStyle);
    setTypeface(customFont);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason (maybe to boost preview) string presentation of constants doesn't transported into numerical values. For `textStyle` property here is [a link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textStyle) to the documentation.

If you want your component handle both preview and runtime you can get style with `getAttributeValue` function and transform it to constant manually:

```
String style = attrs.getAttributeValue(ANDROID_SCHEMA, "textStyle");
int textStyle;
if (style.equals("bold")) {
     textStyle = Typeface.BOLD;
} ...
```

Comment: Thank you Artem! The premisse in your answer is correct, only that the string value will be "0x0" and "0x1" not "normal" and "bold". Using this code as caused me some nasty inflation error which took me a while to figure out.

Comment: Android hides a lot of miracles :) Great investigation, Jay. Bravo!